# Hide or change the power on device logo and model number of a Samsung tablet on power-on

Tags: samsung, 4.4-kitkat, tablet, customization, power-on

For a huge restoration project, a 80's boombox with a TV, I (re-)use an older Samsung Tablet (SM-T650, rooted Android 4.4.4 ) to replace the CRT TV (and to give it some 'brains'). Already customized the tablet with new boot screens that fits the design of the boombox. The tablet it's design, factory default is working in portrait mode however I use it landscape mode (fits better).

I changed the bootscreens/bootanimations with 90 degrees rotated images but the device it's device power-on logo is still in portrait. That is an ugly detail and 'betrays' it is a tablet.

I wonder if it is possible to hide, remove or change the power-on logo? Also want to know how to do this. Any ideas?

---

**Some pictures** (tablet is placed on top of boombox for this purpose instead of mounted inside):

*This is what I want to avoid, hide, remove or change:*

[image: power-on logo]

Later on in the boot sequence (in correct orientation):
[image: bootsamsung]
[image: bootsamsungloop]

Comment: The first logo shown after powering on usually comes from the device bootloader. Theoretically it should be replaceable but finding the necessary tool for such an old tablet may be a challenge. Also the chance to brick the tablet is present.

Comment: @Robert, aha thanks. Bootloader, that seems to be the correct direction. The reason I used an older device is because there is more knowledge how to hack it and less restrictions.